# Transform a list List[String, String] into List[String, List[String]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to take a list of `RawDoc` which each have a `title` and a single `version` and transform it into a list of `Doc` which each have a `title` and all its `versions` collected together into a list:

```
case class RawDoc(title:String, version:String)
case class Doc(title:String, versions:List[String])

val rawDocs:List[RawDoc] = List(
  RawDoc("Green Book", "1.1"),
  RawDoc("Blue Book",  "1.0"),
  RawDoc("Green Book", "1"),
  RawDoc("Blue Book",  "2")
)
```

I would like to start with the above `rawDocs` and create `docs` like this:

```
val docs:List[Doc] = List(
  Doc("Green Book", List("1.1", "1")),
  Doc("Blue Book",  List("1.0", "2"))
)
```

Without using for loops how could this be done in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
val docs = rawDocs.
  groupBy(_.title).map{
    case(title, docsWithSameTitle) => 
      Doc(title, docsWithSameTitle.map(_.version))
  }
```

And if the difference between `"Blue Book"` and `"Blue BooK"` is not incidental typo and they should be treated as equal:

```
val docs = rawDocs.
  groupBy(_.title.toUpperCase).map{
    case(_, docsWithSameTitle) => 
      Doc(docsWithSameTitle.head.title, docsWithSameTitle.map(_.version))
  }
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer... just a tip: you don't need `new` for case classes

Comment: It's also not ideal to shadow `rawDocs`.

Comment: @TravisBrown: true, refactored to much more descriptive name

Comment: Big K was just a typo but having the two answers is instructive.

Comment: I prefer the brevity of DCS's answer but this one more closely matches the mental process I would expect to follow.

Answer (score 4):

```
rawDocs.groupBy(_.title).mapValues(_ map (_.version)).map { 
  case (title, versions) => Doc(title, versions) 
}
```